# When I try to save a category I get "The value of attribute "is_active" must be set"

Tags: magento2

I am on Magento 2.1.7. I have installed the Ultimo theme and am trying to manage the menu. When I save is when I get the error "The value of attribute "is_active" must be set" I can tell I am not the only one who gets it- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6176

I tried running the script in that link but I get the error-

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(../app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No 
such file or directory in /www/sites/www.example.com/files/magento2/project-community-edition/catalogurl.php 
on line 2
```

Are there any other ways to fix this?

Comment: I don't know if the script actually fixes the issue, but the error you posted is easily fixed. You can either edit line 2 in `catalogurl.php` to read: `require_once 'app/bootstrap.php';` or move catalogurl.php to be in some sub-folder of your `project-community-edition` folder... for example `/www/sites/www.example.com/files/magento2/project-community-edition/scripts/catalogurl.php`

Comment: @andyjv you were correct. I moved the script and it ran fine. It did not solve the issue though.